# Server function doesn't appear to be running on Server

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I have a 2 player game that runs in a host-client setup that has a startup sequence that should only be run when both players are connected.

```
public class NetworkGovernor : NetworkManager
{
public override void OnServerAddPlayer(NetworkConnectionToClient conn)
{
    base.OnServerAddPlayer(conn);
    AssignPlayer(conn);
    if (numPlayers > 1)
    {
        PlayerManager P1 = Governor.instance.P1.GetComponent<PlayerManager>();
        PlayerManager P2 = Governor.instance.P2.GetComponent<PlayerManager>();
        P1.RpcLoadData();
        P2.RpcLoadData();
        P1.RpcStartSequence();
        P2.RpcStartSequence();
    }
}

public void AssignPlayer(NetworkConnectionToClient conn)
{
    NetworkIdentity networkIdentity = conn.identity;
    if (Governor.instance.P1 == null)
    {
        Governor.instance.P1 = networkIdentity;
        Debug.Log("branch 1");
        Debug.Log(Governor.instance.P1);
    }
    else
    {
        Governor.instance.P2 = networkIdentity;
        Debug.Log("branch 2");
        Debug.Log(Governor.instance.P1);
    }
}
}
```

I have a class called `Governor` that is a singleton instance and has two variables to store the network identities of the players. This script is attached to the same GameObject as the `NetworkGovernor` (at the root of the scene). For context, the class is setup like this:

```
public class Governor : MonoBehaviour
{
public static Governor instance { get; private set; }
.
.
.
public NetworkIdentity P1;
public NetworkIdentity P2;
private void Awake()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

The expectation is that `OnServerAddPlayer` is run on the Server, so the instance of `Governor` is the same when both players join. However, when both clients join (or more specifically, when the host joins followed by the client), the log shows that branch 1 was run both times (resulting in a null pointer at `P2.RpcLoadData();`). Either my understanding of how the networking works is wrong or there is some incorrect wiring somewhere, but how to I make the server execute the `AssignPlayer` such that it results in both branch 1 and branch 2 being run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above does work as expected, but I had another script `PlayerManager` that had

```
[Server]
public override void OnStartServer()
{
    Governor.instance.P1 = null;
    Governor.instance.P2 = null;
}
```

Which, unexpectedly, seems to run after each call of `OnServerAddPlayer`.